# How to listen Android ActivityTestRule's beforeActivityLaunched method in an android test

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing, android-espresso

How do I listen [ActivityTestRule's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html) [beforeActivityLaunched()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#beforeActivityLaunched()) method in an android test.

My workaround is creating a custom ActivityTestRule and providing a callback on constructor. Is it a bad practice? Same way is it OK to listen for ActivityTestRule constructor method.

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomActivityTestRule<A extends Activity> extends ActivityTestRule<A> {

    public interface onBeforeListener{
        void onBefore(String message);
    }

    private onBeforeListener listener;

    public CustomActivityTestRule(Class<A> activityClass, onBeforeListener listener) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
        super.beforeActivityLaunched();
        listener.onBefore("before activity launch");
    }
}
```

In android test class, I can do something like:

```
@Rule public CustomActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityActivityTestRule = new
            CustomActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class, new CustomActivityTestRule.onBeforeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBefore(String message) {
            //do something before activity starts
        }
    });
```

Same way it is able to do something on junit rule instantiating. Is there any other way to listen for junit test rule instantiating?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override `beforeActivityLaunched` without creation of a new class.

I'm using the following in my tests:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class) {

    @Override
    protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
        super.beforeActivityLaunched();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the test rule so it does not start your activity automatically.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class, false, false);
```

In you setup method you can prepare all what you need and then launch the activity.

```
activityTestRule.launchActivity(null);
```

See also

- [JavaDoc ActivityTestRule constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#ActivityTestRule(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20boolean,%20boolean))
- [JavaDoc launchActivity method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#launchActivity(android.content.Intent))